# Having trouble with blender 2.8's eevee renderer

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

i am having trouble with a barrel-model that i have made using blender 2.8

For some reason, the lower half of my mesh is slightly lighter in color and i can't find the reason why.

This only happens when using the new eevee renderer.

I have tried a couple of things to fix the issue but none of these have worked:

- recalculated normals
- reassigning the texture to faces of the lower half
- played around with the lighting and the HDRI
- removed the bottom half and used a mirror-modifier
- made modifications in the node editor
- removed doubles and looked for issues in the topology.

I am a newbie at blender and the solution might be obvious. But i have searched the internet for an answer and found none. Do some of you guys have any suggestions to how i fix this?

Here's a picture:[image]

Comment: Can you share the blend file?